# ogr2ogr: How to get center point of line?

Tags: ogr2ogr

How to get the center point of a line using ogr2ogr command line?

I am unable to get a proper script to get this work.

Comment: Not exactly what you want: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66972/how-do-i-get-the-centroid-of-line-with-ogr

Answer (score 1):

In theory it can be done by using ogr2ogr with SQL and SQLite dialect. Here is a test command for ogrinfo but the same -sql works also in ogr2ogr.

```
ogrinfo osm.sqlite -dialect sqlite -sql "select Line_Interpolate_Point(geometry,0.5) from lines limit 10"
```

Unfortunately the Line_Interpolate_Point function is very new in Spatialite and if GDAL is compiled with older spatialite version the result will be

> ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare(select
>   Line_Interpolate_Point(geometry,0.5) from lines lim it 10):   no such
>   function: Line_Interpolate_Point

if you do not manage to get a GDAL build that has built with a new enough spatialite you can convert your data into spatialite and run that SELECT with spatilite-gui v1.7.1.